# Svm modeling :: Error in which.max(votematrix[, x]) : subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, svm, prediction

Having a classification problem, I am using SVM for prediction in R. In dataset, there are integer as well as categorical variables. I got error while predicting with predict method.

```
    svp3c <- ksvm(input_dataset3$isCRgt3~., data=input_dataset3,type="C-svc")
    p3<-predict(svp3c,newdata=input_dataset_prediction[,-1],type="response")

    error :: Error in which.max(votematrix[, x]) : subscript out of bounds
```

For this modeling

First : developed model with training dataset

second : saved and Load model for prediction on testing dataset

```
Training Dataset sample

Headning :
head1(int),head2(character-url),head3(character-url),head4(character-url),head5(character),head6(character),haed7(int),head8(int),head9(int),head10(int),head11(int)

Data:    
"0","10","/","/index.php?main_page=logoff","(not set)","rc317a","organic","0","4","20092","5023","0"
"1","11","/","/offwhite-churidar-kameez-set-p-17381.html","(not set)","rc317a","organic","0","4","20092","5023","0"
```

[Download Sample Dataset] http://www.2shared.com/file/tQRapbBt/input_dataset3.html

[Reproduce R script] http://www.2shared.com/file/NpDs5V-9/data1_train.html

Can any one give suggestion?

Comment: Does input_dataset_prediction[,-1] has exactly the same number of columns as input_dataset3 minus one? Also, `svp3c <- ksvm( isCRgt3~., data=input_dataset3,type="C-svc")` should work.

Comment: Thanks January for suggestion,

Comment: @january, I have same numbers of column in input_dataset_prediction and input_dataset3.

Comment: can you post your data files somewhere?

Comment: @Janusary, From this link(http://www.2shared.com/file/tQRapbBt/input_dataset3.html
http://www.2shared.com/file/UNixEOah/input_dataset_prediction.html) you will get sample dataset..

Comment: Ugh, how did you handle all of these text fields? They don't make much sense as factors. Also, I'm not able to reproduce your error message. Can you provide all steps to reproduce your error message starting with reading of the exemplary CSV data?

Comment: hey January, I have provided R modeling with svm script as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem with a different data set.  I first noticed that predict returned fewer predictions than test cases.   It turned out that one of the integer variables in the test dataframe contained NA.  Changing the NA to -1 eliminated the error.
TBC - I haven't thought through the implications of setting the variable to -1 but it has eliminated the error and now get the correct number of predictions.